# Does Coreboot/SeaBIOS support GPT partition table?

Tags: gentoo, gpt, mbr, partition-table, coreboot

Few days ago, I flashed my x230 with coreboot with this [tutorial](https://www.chucknemeth.com/laptop/lenovo-x230/flash-lenovo-x230-coreboot).

Now, while I was installing [Funtoo](https://www.funtoo.org/)  using its [GPT-Partitioning](https://www.funtoo.org/Install/GPT_Partitioning) guide (not using [MBR-Partitioning](https://www.funtoo.org/Install/MBR_Partitioning)),
I got following error:

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

Does this mean, Coreboot/SeaBIOS only use MBR partitioning ?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS are not directly related to partitioning. Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot or MBR for BIOS boot. Ubuntu and most Linux can boot in either mode from either partitions. BIOS systems only need to find MBR or very first sector of hard drive. And gpt has a protective MBR that can be used for BIOS boot. If using grub with gpt & BIOS boot you need a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. My 2006 BIOS only laptop boots from gpt.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, **coreboot+SeaBIOS *DOES* support GPT partitioning**!

The comment stressing that having UEFI or BIOS firmware is orthogonal to what kinds of partition table your boot disk can have is correct:

- UEFI supports MBR and GPT
- BIOS support MBR and GPT¹
- coreboot+SeaBIOS supports MBR and GPT¹

¹You just have to go through the hoop of making a BIOS boot partition for GPT on BIOS and coreboot+SeaBIOS.

I recently got a Librem 14 laptop with coreboot+SeaBIOS, and I wondered the same thing: will coreboot pose some special obstacle to using GPT partitioning? (Punching that into a search engine led me to this question!) Happily, I can report that using the classic BIOS/GPT layout worked for me.

## Basic install

Sadly, I've never installed Gentoo (the distro I used was Arch), and I can't know why your system complained about EFI variables, but hopefully I can give some information transferable across distro installations:

- I used [the basic BIOS/GPT partitioning scheme](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#BIOS/GPT_layout_example), except for the swap partition (I use a swap file).

  Using `gdisk`, I GPT-partitioned my drive (`/dev/nvme0n1`), [created a 1 MiB BIOS boot partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_(GPT)_specific_instructions), followed by a root partition spanning the rest of the drive.

  The BIOS boot partition has *no filesystem* (`FSTYPE`) *or mountpoint*, and my root partition's ext4.

  `lsblk -o name,parttypename,fstype,size,mountpoint`

  ```
  NAME             PARTTYPENAME     FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT
  nvme0n1
  ├─nvme0n1p1      BIOS boot                        1M
  └─nvme0n1p2      Linux filesystem ext4        931.5G /
  ```
- I then installed GRUB: `grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/nvme0n1`

  (You might be thinking, '*What?! `i386-pc`??? I am NOT on a 32-bit CPU from 1985!*' But this is `grub-install`'s default flag, and it *is* the flag to use for x86-64 BIOS systems, including coreboot+SeaBIOS ones. I only mention it here to explain its appearance in other sources and to dissuade one from including an incorrect flag, such as `x86_64-efi`, which is UEFI-only.)

  After this, you'd set any preferable GRUB settings by editing `/etc/default/grub` (but I didn't set any).

  Then I generated the GRUB config file: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

After that, I installed a display manager and desktop environment, enabled some services, and rebooted into my new Arch install. I'm tempted to list *all* the gory details of my installation (I roughly followed [the Arch installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide)), but they'd be very out of scope here; the key pieces of information should be the partitioning scheme and GRUB installation listed above.

## Install with LUKS disk encryption

For encrypting a GPT disk on coreboot+SeaBIOS, a setup that works is the basic one above plus [encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Encrypting_devices_with_cryptsetup) of the root partition (`p3`) and the addition of an unencrypted, ~500 MiB `/boot` partition (`p2`).

`lsblk -o name,parttypename,fstype,size,mountpoint`

```
NAME             PARTTYPENAME     FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                       931.5G
├─nvme0n1p1      BIOS boot                        1M
├─nvme0n1p2      Linux filesystem ext2          512M /boot
└─nvme0n1p3      Linux filesystem crypto_LUKS   931G
  └─cryptroot                     ext4          931G /
```

#### Bonus info

For anyone wondering how to go about this with the above partitioning scheme, first make the encrypted the root partition, open it, and format it.

```
cryptsetup --verify-passphrase --verbose luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p3
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 cryptroot
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/cryptroot
```

Then mount it and the `/boot` partition...

```
mount /dev/mapper/cryptroot /mnt
mkdir /mnt/boot
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot
```

...and, for Arch, generally follow the thrust of the [install guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Mount_the_file_systems) from there on.

When time comes to set up the bootloader (GRUB), the only difference from the GRUB installation details in the **Basic install** section above is that you *will* want to configure a GRUB setting in `/etc/default/grub`, where you'll want to edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` var at the top to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=XXXXXX:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot"
```

where `XXXXXX` is the UUID of the *outer*, encrypted root partition, `nvme0n1p3` (*not* the inner, decrypted root partition, `cryptroot`):

`lsblk -o name,uuid`

```
NAME             UUID
...
└─nvme0n1p3      XXXXXX
  └─cryptroot
```

Then generate the GRUB config file and proceed as in the **Basic install** section.